# About the JSBI format of token price

Tags: uniswap, nodejs, ethereumjs, ethers.js

I followed the Uniswap sdk to set up the pool instance and then the token price in the pool by using:

```
const token0price = poolExample.token0Price
```

But then when I query token0price.numerator, it returns a JSBI list as follows:

JSBI(7) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4096, sign: false ].

Then if I convert it to string, it returns as this:

2005105501692849753489918455171055731573804524062937603023576183049.

I didn't quite get what has happened and how the JSBI list can be converted into the number. I would appreciate if anyone could explain this to me. Cheers.